# How to disable a dropdown option in a servlet using javascript

Tags: javascript, java, servlets

I saw another question's answer [here](https://jsfiddle.net/p2SFA/1/) which used javascript to disable dropdown options after they were selected. How can I use this in a java servlet?

```
Monday (html form):
1st:(Dropdown menu showing all available activities)
2nd:(Dropdown menu showing all available activities)
3rd:(Dropdown menu showing all available activities)
(Submit changes for this day)

Tuesday (html form):
1st:(Dropdown menu showing all available activities)
2nd:(Dropdown menu showing all available activities)
3rd:(Dropdown menu showing all available activities)
(Submit changes for this day)

Wednesday (html form):
1st:(Dropdown menu showing all available activities)
2nd:(Dropdown menu showing all available activities)
3rd:(Dropdown menu showing all available activities)
(Submit changes for this day)

...
...
```

Comment: It's not clear what you mean.  Are you looking to perform this same logic in Java, posting the page back to the server with each selection?  Are you looking to just put this JavaScript code as-is (with minor modifications to fit your HTML) in your page?  Something else?  What have you tried and what isn't working?

Comment: I'd like to know if it's possible to either implement the javascript code into the servlet. If not, what is a good solution to disable/remove dropdown options after they have been selected elsewhere? E.g. Monday Activities={park, windsurfing, museum}. If Monday 1st choice has been selected as park, show only windsurfing and museum on the other two choices until another has been chosen. Hope that clears it up :P

Comment: try to use `jsp` instead of `servlet` ,there you can easily implement your `javascript` code .

Comment: This is possible but your `doGet` (i.e. servlet code) will look messy because you'll have something like `out.println("javascript code here");`. Better do it with JSF or thru a template engine (e.g. freemarker, thymeleaf).